# How to fix 'cannot import name 'process_pdf' from 'pdfminer.pdfinterp'' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pdfminer, pdf-to-html

I am trying to convert texts in pdf file to text or HTML format, but this error is occurring frequently 
'cannot import name 'process_pdf' from 'pdfminer.pdfinterp' '
How can I remove this ?

I have tried this code in the visual basic studio, but it's still not working , but in that case, I got indentation error due to spaces, so I tried this in the jupyter notebook and got this error.

```py
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager , process_pdf
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layput import LAParams



def to_txt(pdf_path):
    input_ = file(pdf_path , 'rb')
    output = StringIO()

    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams = LAParams())
    process_pdf(manager, converter, input_)

    return output.getvalue()

b = to_txt(rb"C:\Users\Jasvinder Singh\Desktop\HACK-IN REPORT.docx")

ImportError: cannot import name 'process_pdf' from 'pdfminer.pdfinterp' (C:\Users\Jasvinder Singh\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfinterp.py)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you think `process_pdf` is a method in `pdfminer.pdfinterp`?

Comment: @vekerdyb as I am getting started with this new field, I searched for codes here on stack overflow, but it was showing codes more than 12 months or older, so I chose to go with it. Also, I  was searching for its documentation but can't get an appropriate site. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the [documentation](http://www.unixuser.org/~euske/python/pdfminer/programming.html) and [this comment on a bug](https://github.com/euske/pdfminer/issues/34#issuecomment-28643658).

The `process_pdf` method has been replaced by `PDFPage.get_pages()`.